# SSIS:Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: ssis

I am working on simple ssis package i.e. source is oledb sql and destination is excel. Loading 1 table data into excel. Table contains around 400 000 records. Package is running successfully while running from direct visual studio. But getting error from SQL agent job after automation.

Error is:

> Script Task:Error: The Execute method on the task returned error code 0x80070008 (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)). The Execute method must succeed, and indicate the result using an "out" parameter.

Comment: That error sounds as though you're trying to do some UI stuff in the package.  Perhaps a MsgBox?  This doesn't work on the server: shouldn't be using UI things like System.Windows.Forms in a package (except for VS debugging, but Watch and breakpoints are better for that).

Comment: I am not doing any UI stuff.only exporting data to excel using DFT.Source is SQL table and destination is excel.Nothing else.